# Double subscript and superscript

Tags: subscripts

I have tried several approach and search for similar cases but I couldn't make this working. 
[image]

As you can see the highlighted yellow looks improper and wrong. I would like to fix the following issues

1) make the subscript and superscript smaller

2) remove the space between sigma and its subscript

3)  when i add sigma with subscript beta in the denominator they look like multiplication

I used the following code

```
$\beta_1,\frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{S_{xx}}$ and $\sigma^2_{\beta_i}$ and $\frac{\hat{\beta}_i-\beta_i}{\sigma_{\beta_i}}$

I tried using the below code but didn't work also.

\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{4} % \scriptsize is 7 pt

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{5}{2}{1} % \tiny is 5 pt  {S}{t}{s}{ss}
```

Comment: I suggest `\sigma^{}_{\beta_1}` for the third case and the similar ones.

Comment: Please tell us what "I couldn't make this working" entails. Are you getting error and/or warning messages?

Comment: Looks wrong because it looks as multiplication not subscripts. I used \sigma^{}_{\beta_1} before and wasn't helpful

Comment: Mico i can get it small subscript or superscript and without space

Comment: Incidentally, I think there's a typo in the screenshot you posted: In the second row, `\hat{beta}_0` should be distributed normally about `\beta_0` and not about `\beta_1`, right?

Answer (score 4):

I'm inferring that you're not happy with the basic "look" because you would like the subscripts of `\sigma` to be less far away, i.e, they should be snugged up to the left. If this is the concern, just write `\sigma_{\!\beta_1}`, `\sigma_{\!\beta_1}`, etc.

You may also want to settle on a standard size for the fraction terms. In your screenshot `\frac` (or `\dfrac`) appears to be employed for the left-hand material, whereas `\tfrac` appears to be used for the material to the right of `\Rightarrow`. I would choose one or the other look, but not mix 'em up in one and the same equation. Speaking for myself, I prefer `\frac` look (with larger parentheses) to the `\tfrac` look (with smaller parentheses).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
%% look 1: \tfrac and \big parentheses
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\hat{\beta}_1 &\sim N\bigl(\beta_1,\tfrac{\sigma^2_{\!\epsilon}}{S_{xx}}\bigr) \sim N(\beta_1,\sigma^2_{\!\beta_1})
&&\Rightarrow \tfrac{\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1}{\sigma^{}_{\!\beta_1}}
=\tfrac{\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1}{\sigma^{}_{\!\epsilon}/\sqrt{S_{xx}}} \sim N(0,1)\\
\hat{\beta}_0 &\sim N\bigl(\beta_0,\sigma^2_{\!\epsilon} \bigl[\tfrac{1}{n}+\tfrac{\bar{X}^2}{S_{xx}}\bigr]\bigr)
\sim N(\beta_1,\sigma^2_{\!\beta_0})
&&\Rightarrow \tfrac{\hat{\beta}_0-\beta_0}{\sigma^{}_{\!\beta_1}}
=\tfrac{\hat{\beta}_0-\beta_0}{\sigma^{}_{\!\epsilon} 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar{X}^2}{S_{xx}}}}
\sim N(0,1)
\end{alignat*}

%% look 2: \frac and \bigg parentheses
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\hat{\beta}_1 &\sim N\biggl(\beta_1,\frac{\sigma^2_{\!\epsilon}}{S_{xx}}\biggr) \sim N(\beta_1,\sigma^2_{\!\beta_1})
&&\Rightarrow \frac{\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1}{\sigma^{}_{\!\beta_1}}
=\frac{\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1}{\sigma^{}_{\!\epsilon}/\sqrt{S_{xx}}} \sim N(0,1)\\
\hat{\beta}_0 &\sim N\biggl(\beta_0,\sigma^2_{\!\epsilon} \biggl[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar{X}^2}{S_{xx}}\biggr]\biggr)
\sim N(\beta_1,\sigma^2_{\!\beta_0})
&&\Rightarrow \frac{\hat{\beta}_0-\beta_0}{\sigma^{}_{\!\beta_1}}
=\frac{\hat{\beta}_0-\beta_0}{\sigma^{}_{\!\epsilon} 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar{X}^2}{S_{xx}}}}
\sim N(0,1)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```